# Listview inside tabpager fragment not showing

Tags: java, android, listview, layout, android-fragments

Im trying to add a listview inside a fragment witch is also inside a tabhost. the app is not crashing or anything, but the list view is not showing anything.
Here is my code:

Class for the tabPager

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentHome();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentBadges();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentBenefits();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Following is the fragment where I want the listview:

```
    public class FragmentBadges extends Fragment {

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_badges_list, null);

                BadgesListAdapter adapter = new BadgesListAdapter(this.getActivity(), getCurrentBadges());
                ListView badgeslist = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.badges_list);
                badgeslist.setAdapter(adapter);
                badgeslist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        //TODO do some
                    }
                });

                return rootView;
            }
```

And following is the adapter:

```
public class BadgesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private List<Badge> badges;

    public BadgesListAdapter(Activity context, List<Badge> badges) {
        super(context, R.layout.fragment_badges_listrow);
        this.context = context;
        this.badges = badges;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_badges_listrow, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        txtTitle.setText(badges.get(position).getName());

        imageView.setImageResource(badges.get(position).getDrawableValue());

        return rowView;
    }
```

while debugging I found out that the getView method inside the badgesListAdapter is never called.
I have this same code for another app but without the tabpager and there it all works perfectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by inhering ListFragment in FragmentBadges, following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heR4zhj_wV0

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `getCurrentBadges()` method not returns empty list. If so there is no data to show in `ListView`.

Comment: So maybe try to use `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)` constructor to provide your data by calling `super(context, R.layout.fragment_badges_listrow, badges.toArray())` in `BadgesListAdapter` constructor.

Comment: I change everything to mach that constructor, but the getView() method it's never call neither.